# Jquery object as variable, each of its childs

Tags: jquery, object, each, children

I want to make some jquery slider function.
Im using code:

```
var parentElement = $('#slidercontent');
```

In this object i have a ul element with li elements (childrens).
I want to make a each function and get all childrens of this element.

I try some combinations for ex:

```
parentElement.each(function(){ 
console.log('its a li!');
});

parentElement.children().each(function(){ 
console.log('its a li!');
});
```

but this not working effective.

Comment: Can you post the markup ? The second one should work

Comment: nevermind, its a console log problem... i try alert and its ok...

Comment: You can always delete the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    var parentElement = $('#slidercontent');
    parentElement.children().each(function(){ 
       //use $(this).children() to get children's children
       console.log($(this).children());
   });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/VfD52/